# restoring chained selects using angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two select-element that are bound to a model in angular. The first should show a list of processes, the second a list of variables belonging to the process. My datamodel looks like this:

```
"processes": [
    {
        "name": "proces1",
        "variables": [
            "var1",
            "var2"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "proces2",
        "variables": [
            "var3",
            "var4"
        ]
    }
]
```

The result of my selection needs to end up in a 'slider' object in the 'sliders' array on the scope:

```
$scope.sliders = 
[
  {
    process : "process1",
    tag     : "var1",
  }
]
```

I've implemented the selects as below, inspired by [this](http://jsfiddle.net/pythondave/JUZDf/) jsfiddle.

```
<tr ng-repeat="slider in sliders track by $index">
    <td><select name="processSelect"  ng-model="slider.process" ng-options="process.name for process in slider.processes"></select></td>
    <td><select name="variableSelect" ng-model="slider.tag"     ng-options="v for v in slider.process.variables"></select></td>
</tr>
```

The approach works, however if my model is already filled only the variableSelect is selected. The process select is not. This is caused because the processSelect uses a a list of process dictionaries instead of strings (which are stored in the model).

What can I do to achieve this? How does one normally accomplish this in angular?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by changing my data model slightly to:

```
"processes": {
    "process1": [
        "var1",
        "var2"
    ],
    "process2": [
        "var3",
        "var4"
    ]
}
```

then I changed the ng-options to:

```
<tr ng-repeat="slider in sliders track by $index">
 <td><select name="processSelect" ng-model="slider.process" ng-options="key as key for (key, value) in processes"></select></td>
 <td><select name="variableSelect" ng-model="slider.tag" ng-options="value for (key, value) in processes[slider.process]"></select></td>
</tr>
```

basically following the angular docs on [ng-options](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions).